# How to serialize form data by number in javascript and submit with a specific number

Tags: javascript, serialization

I'm working on a personal project, where I've more forms than one (comment forms under each post). Each form I give a number according to post id.

```html
<form id="postCommentsForm<?php echo $ansRow['id'];?>" class="form">
       <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <a href="user/<?php echo $username;?>">
         <img class="p-1 m-0" src="images/<?php echo $userAvatar;?>" width="35" height="35" alt="<?php echo $userAvatar;?> profile picture">
        </a>
          <input name="post_comment<?php echo $ansRow['id'];?>" id="add_comments" type="text" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="add_comments form-control pl-3 pr-3" placeholder="<?php echo $userFname;?>, type something" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-form">
          <input type="text" hidden id="question_id" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
          <input type="text" hidden id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="<?php echo $ansRow['id'];?>">
          <input type="text" hidden id="session_id" name="session_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary submit-comments" type="submit" name="submit_comment<?php echo $ansRow['id'];?>" id="postComments">Comment</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

javascript code

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[id^=postCommentsForm]").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
    var add_comments = $("#add_comments").val();
    var question_id = $("#question_id").val();
    var answer_id = $("#answer_id").val();
    // var session_id = $("#session_id").val();
    
    if(add_comments == "" ){
        $("#error-message").html("All fields are required!").slideDown();
        $("#success-message").slideUp();
  
    }else{
  //Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: "include/forms-data/comments.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        add_comments: add_comments,
        question_id: question_id,
        answer_id: answer_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data != 0) {
          $("[id^=postCommentsForm").trigger("reset");
            $("#success-message").html("Question Added Successfully!").slideDown();
            $("#error-message").slideUp(); 
      } else {
        //alert("Can't save record"); 
            $("#error-message").html("Something went wrong!").slideDown(); 
            $("#success-message").slideUp();
      }
    }
  });
  
        }
      });
  });
```

How I can fetch #comments(postID here), and submit form data successfully under the postID?

I hope I define well the question.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's "starts with selector" can help. [check out here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=comments]").click(function(e) {
      var element_id = this.getAttribute("id");
    });
});
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=comments]").click(function(e) {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='comments1'>b</button>
<button id='comments2'>a</button>
```

Comment: can you please explain here, while I've three files, one `index.php`, `comments.js`, and `comments.php`. How to get id, That is my question. Thanks

Comment: this is the answer for "How I can fetch #comments(postID here)". you can fetch all the elements that their id's start with comments by "start with selector".

Comment: You can include your js file to your php file that contains elements which you talked about begining of your question(form elements). And do whatever you want

Comment: actually, I've to send a record to the database under the post, `postID` is the, can you please write the required code, what exactly I've to code? Thanks

Comment: ok i am going to edit my answer. look at it.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` part is gives you the pressed element's id.

Comment: but i think what you want to do is something else. I think this might help: you can add a hidden element to the form that this element's value is the id. and when you send the form to php file take that hidden element's value which is the id. and do the request with that id.

Comment: Boom, Thank you very much, This is what I was looking for.

Comment: But one issue occurred, the form display error message for each form (encase that is blank), but when some types some text and submitting, then error message displays for each form accepting first form. Please help, I updated the main code above. Thanks

Comment: I answered your question and you accepted it. If you have another problem open another question. People who have the same proplem with your question might look this post and make use of that. That's why you shouldn't update your question every time you have another problem.

Comment: Yes, bro, I accepted this question but it is not completed yet, I was just excited to see the first error message, but when I type anything that is still showing the error message. please have a look at my code is that fine? Please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226813/discussion-between-dolmushcu-and-sami-ullah).